# How to fulfill a map by max values with a help of triplet operator

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a  map, which I want to fulfill by max values. 
What I want:
1. if `key` doesn't exist or `value > mymap[key]` then `mymap[key] = value` 
2. otherwise, I don't want to rewrite `mymap[key]` value

I have strong impression that everything written below could be done in one line with the help of triplet operator

```
    if (mymap.find(key) != mymap.end()) 
    {
        mymap[key] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        if (value > mymap[key]) mymap[key] = value;
    }
```

I'd do smth like

```
mymap[key] = value > mymap[key] ? value : mymap[key];
```

but if `key` doesn't exists this would create `mymap[key] = 0`, and the problem is that `value` could be negative.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just use the working code you already have?  Is there something wrong with using several lines of easy to read code?

Comment: @NathanOliver, because there is a more simple and easy-to-read solution for the case then `value` is positive.

Comment: Your example can preform up to 3 searches for `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you search the map for a key several times. Generally it is best to save the result of find in order to use it for manipulations later so you aren't researching the map for the key each time.

How about this?

```
const auto it = mymap.find(key);
if (it != mymap.end())
{
    it->second = std::max(value, it->second);
}
else
{
    mymap.emplace(key, value);
}
```

Comment: @tkrishtop No problem, happy to help. If this answer solves your issue please consider accepting the answer.